# Are there any specific enterprise security concerns with deploying a Machine Learning model on the Cloud

Tags: security, machine-learning, deployment

We are building a platform that aims to deliver machine learning solutions for large enterprises with significant data security concerns. All data training is done on premise with restrictions on the nature of data used for model training. Once the model is completed, I am looking to deploy this on cloud with standard security/ audit standards.(IP whitelists, access tokens, logs)

I believe the features can be completed anonymized (normalized, PCA etc) to provide an additional layer of security. **Is there any way the data sent to the cloud-based ML model can lead back to the original data?**

While I had reviewed other questions around model deployment, this aspect of security isn't handled specifically. 
https://dzone.com/articles/security-attacks-analysis-of-machine-learning-mode
(concern is not on availability or model distortion- but more around confidential data)

Again, idea is to retain learning and data on premise and only the deployment on cloud for speed, flexibility and availability.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way the data sent to the cloud-based ML model can lead back to the original data?

Any function that has an inverse, can lead back to the original data.  The risk is not just from a random person viewing the data, but an insider threat within the team. Here is an example:

[How to reverse PCA and reconstruct original variables from several principal components?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com)

Depending on the number of principal components, it may also be possible to brute-force guess the Eigenvectors.